# SQL UPDATE при выполнении условия

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста с апдейтом, кейс следующий:

Есть таблица TABLE1 : SITEORDER - уникальный номер заказа в БД, SITELINE - уникальная строка заказа в БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо выполнить апдейт поля SITESTAT=0 где SITEVAL=2, если для уникального номера SITEORDER нет пустых значений в поле SITEVAL.

На основе таблицы выше я ожидаю, что апдейт выполнит изменения для 5, 14 и 15 строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Набросал такое, но вижу явно что-то упускаю, так как ничего не апдейчу, хоть должно быть 3 строки  :(

```
UPDATE TABLE1
   SET SITESTAT = 0
 WHERE SITEORDER = SITEORDER
   AND SITEVAL = 2
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
          FROM TABLE1
         WHERE SITEORDER = SITEORDER
           AND SITEVAL IS NULL);
```

Comment: *`.. WHERE SITEORDER = SITEORDER ..`* Надо ли объяснять, что это эквивалентно `.. WHERE SITEORDER IS NOT NULL ..`? что для показанных данных вообще считай эквивалентно `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 L
   SET L.SITESTAT = 0
   WHERE L.SITEVAL = 2
   AND NOT IN (SELECT C.SITEORDER
          FROM TABLE1 C
         WHERE C.SITEVAL IS NULL
         GROUP BY C.SITEORDER);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT siteorder
               FROM table 
               GROUP BY 1
               HAVING NOT SUM(siteval IS NULL)
               ) t2
SET t1.sitestat = 0
WHERE t1.siteval = 2
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, не использовал ранее NATURAL JOIN, проверил у себя запрос, к сожалению не срабатывает, получаю ORA-00933, не хватает знаний понять в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста или может есть еще вариант аналога для данного запроса

Comment: @Albert *запрос, к сожалению не срабатывает, получаю ORA-00933, не хватает знаний понять в чем проблема* О! На этот вопрос очень легко ответить... Вы даже не знаете, с каким сервером БД работаете. OracleDB - это вот ни разу не MySQL ! И то, что запрос для одной СУБД не работает в другой - скорее норма, чем исключение.

Comment: Действительно могу не знать, так как продолжаю изучать, спасибо за отзыв!